# Assigning attachment on lead conversion to opportunity

Tags: trigger, opportunity, attachment, leads, lead-conversion

I have a problem with apex code thats supposed to delete attachment added to account after lead conversion, and then add the copy of this attachment to opportunity.

But when i convert my lead, nothing happens, i checked the Attachment.ParentID with system debug and i found something strange.
 The normal id of account is 0013600000LjlAi, but when in the debug its 0013600000LjlAiAAJ, do you know why that would happen?

Here is part of code responsible for getting parentId:

---

```
trigger Update_Attachment_Parent on Attachment (after insert, after update) {
List<Id> forDeletionIds = new List<Id>();

for (Attachment a : trigger.new){

if(a.ParentId.getSobjectType() == Account.SobjectType){

Account parent = [SELECT Primary_Opportunity__c FROM Account WHERE ID = :a.ParentId]; 

System.debug('The parentID is: ' + a.ParentId);
```

---

Side note: Person Accounts are enabled for our org and every converted account is a person account.

```
trigger AddOppToAcc on Lead (After Update) {
List<Account> oUpdList = new List<Account> ();
for (Lead l : Trigger.new) 
if (l.IsConverted && l.convertedAccountId != null)
oUpdList.add(new Account(id = l.convertedAccountId,Primary_Opportunity__c = l.convertedOpportunityId));

update oUpdList;
}
```

The whole part of attachment code:

```
trigger Update_Attachment_Parent on Attachment (after insert, after update) {
List<Id> forDeletionIds = new List<Id>();
for (Attachment a : trigger.new){

if(a.ParentId.getSobjectType() == Account.SobjectType){

Account parent = [SELECT Primary_Opportunity__c FROM Account WHERE ID = :a.ParentId]; 

System.debug('The parentID is: ' + a.ParentId);

if (parent.Primary_Opportunity__c != null){
Attachment body = [SELECT Body FROM Attachment WHERE Id = :a.Id];
Attachment newA = New Attachment(
Name = a.Name,
Body = body.Body,
OwnerId = a.OwnerId,
parentId = parent.Primary_Opportunity__c);
insert newA;
forDeletionIds.add(a.Id);
}
}
}
List<Attachment> forDeletion = [SELECT Id FROM Attachment WHERE Id IN :forDeletionIds];
delete forDeletion;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The conversion of `0013600000LjlAi` to `0013600000LjlAiAAJ` is done by salesforce. The difference is 15 digit Id is case sensitive and 18 digit Id is case insensitive.

Now, Since you are converting a lead and on the lead conversion, I believe you have written a trigger on lead object as well.

Please ensure that **Require Validation for Converted Leads** is checked in Lead Settings so that the triggers are fired.

Comment: I have a trigger on lead, that assigns opportunity to account field that is a lookup to opp, Require Validation is enabled.